# Using Scalaz stream, how to convert A => Task[B] to Process1[A,B]

Tags: scala, scalaz, scalaz-stream

I am encoding a http request to a remote server as a function which takes an id and yields a Task[JValue].

I would like to convert that function into a Process1, to simplify my program (By simplify, i mean use Processes as building blocks as much as possible)

I would like to convert the function

```
    reqDoc(id:A):Task[B]
```

(where A is the type of the Id, and B is the type of the response)
into

```
    reqDoc:Process1[A,B]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think you want a `Process1`, I think that if you were creating a `Process1` out of this you would be creating a `Process1[A, Task[B]]` which isn't what you want.

I think you want to create a `Channel` that you can attach a `Process` to that would give you a new `Process`.  A `Channel` is just an alias for a `Process` that produces effectful functions.

```
type Channel[+F[_],-I,O] = Process[F, I => F[O]]
```

Since you have one function, you are just going to create a process which produces an infinite stream of the same function, which `constant`

```
// a String => Task[Int] that we'll make a channel from
val length: String => Task[Int] = (x => Task.delay(x.length))
// a channel is just a source of functions:
val lengthChannel = Process.constant(length)
```

Now given a Process that produces Strings (here we'll produce just one):

```
val source: Process[Task,String] = Process.emit("asdf")
```

We can create a process by running our source through our channel

```
val lengths = source through lengthChannel
```

and we can run our process and get the length of "asdf"

```
scala> lengths.runLog.run
res5: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Int] = Vector(4)
```